# .VBS to run DNSCMD /enumrecords in a for loop on an array of node names. CLI shows as if I ran a DNSCMD /?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, syntax-error

I'm trying to run DNSCMD.exe /enumrecords from a .vbs on our Windows Server 2003 DNS server and dump the results into a .csv file for each node name under a DNS Zone.

I have entered the Nodes I want to run the command against under the zone into an array and entered a list of filenames into another array.

The idea being to run a for loop to walk through each node name and file name 0-42 and run the command for each node name and outputting to each filename in sequence.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ncpArr, NODE, fnameArr, FILE, DNSCMD, objWSHShell, QComm
Set objWSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ncpArr = Array(42 item array of DNS Nodes)

fnameArr = Array(42 item array of filenames)

QComm = "DnsCmd DNSservername /enumrecords contoso.com " & ncpArr(NODE) & " /Additional> c:\DNSData\" & fnameArr(NODE) & ".csv"

For NODE = 0 to 42
objWSHShell.Run QComm,1,True
'objWshShell.Exec QComm
'wscript.echo "| " & ncpArr(NODE) & " | | " & fnameArr(NODE) & " |"
'wscript.echo DNSCMD
Next
```

The intent was to save myself some time but if anything I've tripled the time it would have taken to run these 42 commands while writing this script.

What I have figured out so far is:

When I run this command on the DNS server it outputs a CSV exactly like I want it to

```
DnsCmd dnsservername /enumrecords zone.name node.st.name /Additional /continue> c:\DNSData\state_city_net.csv
```

When I run the same command like this:

```
Set objWSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objWSHShell.run "dnscmd /enumrecords zone.name node.st.name /additional> c:\DNSData\state_city_net.csv"
```

The command line box pops up briefly showing the instructions for DNSCMD as if I ran a DNSCMD /?. I've only been able to get a look at it by running the loop above and hitting Pause/Break at just the right time. Not sure if it's possible to get the Command Line box to stay open to show any errors

One thing I noticed is normally when you run it with an incorrect syntax it will have some information about the error at the top. In this case it literally looks like the DNSCMD /? instructions with no error at the top.

I'm seriously wondering if it's just not possible to run DNSCMD /enumrecords using a .vbs. as you can see from the commented out parts I've tried a few things to show the syntax is correct. When I Echo the output of the loop I can enter the exact syntax into the command line on the DNS server and it works!

If ANYONE could just peek at what I have above and tell me why when I run my script it does that or if you could even just confirm that my scripting is sound and it's something with DNSCMD it would really help me sleep better.

Thanks 
Drew

Answer (score 0):

When you enter

```
DnsCmd dnsservername /enumrecords zone.name node.st.name /Additional /continue> c:\DNSData\state_city_net.csv
```

in a shell ('DOS box'), the redirection (>) is provided by this shell. Your

```
objWSHShell.run "dnscmd /enumrecords zone.name node.st.name /additional> c:\DNSData\state_city_net.csv"
```

just runs a process and can't do redirection. Change your line to

```
objWSHShell.run "%comspec% /c dnscmd /enumrecords zone.name node.st.name /additional> c:\DNSData\state_city_net.csv"
```

and think about the (missing) /continue. For (single) testing, you can change the /c (close when done) to /k (keep open). Probably re-reading about (using?) all three parameters of the .Run method and paying attention to the return value may be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks so much you really saved my sanity! I was able to get it working.

The loop wouldn't step to the next item in the array until I removed %comspec% /c from the DNSCMD command and ran it as:
    objWSHShell.Run "%comspec% /c" & QComm & "",1,True